# JSF ui:repeat vs h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, uirepeat, htmldatatable

Before asking this question, I visited many other related ones and tried to gather the maximum of information. But, what I found till now let me understand that there is no real/major difference between `ui:repeat` and `h:dataTable`, and that whenever we can use `h:dataTable` we can also use `ui:repeat` (sometimes one of them is a little complex than the other, but at the end we got same results).

So, is there any use cases where the only choice is to use `h:dataTable`? or the opposite (only choice is `ui:repeat`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *is there any use cases where the only choice is to use h:dataTable?*

- If you want to use an [`UIData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html)-based component (with all of its special attributes absent in `UIRepeat`).
- If you want to render a HTML `<table>` by a JSF component.
- If you want to be able to customize the `<table>` rendering (like PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` does with sorting, filtering, grouping, folding, lazyloading, etc, etc).
- If you aren't using Facelets as view technology.

> *or the opposite (only choice is ui:repeat)?*

- If you don't want any of above and thus need a pure markup-less iteration component.
- If you want to be able to skip every *n* items during iteration (using `step` attribute).

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for your prompt answer. one last question, is there an alternative way in `h:datatable` regarding the `step` attribute of `ui:repeat` ?

Comment: There isn't (apart from just preparing the model the view needs) . Updated answer.

Comment: Wait, datatable isn"t part of the facelet view technology ? I thought facelet was englobing every ui, f and h.